# What's good style for preconditions in Spock feature methods?

Tags: spock

In a feature method, one specifies the feature action in a `when:` block, the result of which gets tested in a subsequent `then:` block. Often preparation is needed, which is done in a `given:` clause (or `setup:` or fixture method). It is equally useful to include preconditions: these are conditions which are not the subject of the feature test (thus should not be in a `when:`-`then:` or `expect:`) but they assert/document necessary conditions for the test to be meaningful. See for example the dummy spec below:

```
import spock.lang.*

class DummySpec extends Specification {
  def "The leading three-caracter substring can be extracted from a string"() {
    given: "A string which is at least three characters long"
    def testString = "Hello, World"

    assert testString.size() > 2

    when: "Applying the appropriate [0..2] operation"
    def result = testString[0..2]

    then: "The result is three characters long"
    result.size() == 3
  }
}
```

What is the suggested practice for these preconditions? I used `assert` in the example but many frown upon `assert`s in a Spec.

Comment: This is what I'd do. There's nothing wrong with using `assert` in a spec when needed (it's still a Spock condition, not a Groovy assertion).

Answer (score 7):

I've been always using `expect` for such scenarios:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class DummySpec extends Specification {
  def "The leading three-caracter substring can be extracted from a string"() {
    given: "A string which is at least three characters long"
    def testString = "Hello, World"

    expect: "Input should have at least 3 characters"
    testString.size() > 3

    when: "Applying the appropriate [0..2] operation"
    def result = testString[0..2]

    then: "The result is three characters long"
    result.size() == 3
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, @opal, I myself actually prefer `assert` to `expect` and am following @peter-niederwieser's advice.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't believe that this is *suggested practice*, another alternative that helps retain the English-language readability of the code is using the descriptive `and:` clause provided by Spock.

```
def "The leading three-character substring can be extracted from a string"() {
    given: "A test string"
    def testString = "Hello, World"

    and: "the input should have at least 3 characters"
    testString.size() > 3

    when: "Applying the appropriate [0..2] operation"
    def result = testString[0..2]

    then: "The result is three characters long"
    result.size() == 3
}
```

Since `and:` doesn't have any special meaning when Spock compiles your test method, you can use it as much as you like and wherever you would like within the test method.

Comment: The test will not fail in this case if `testString` has less than three characters. The intent is to enforce the preconditions.